Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch when using Passsenger with Apache2 for rails application
Here is the error:
Your Ruby version is 3.0.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.7 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
  /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/definition.rb:469:in `validate_ruby!'
  /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/definition.rb:444:in `validate_runtime!'
  /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler.rb:143:in `setup'
  /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
  /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/ui/shell.rb:136:in `with_level'
  /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/ui/shell.rb:88:in `silence'
  /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
  <internal:/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
  <internal:/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:382:in `activate_gem'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:221:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:546:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:220:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:91:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:189:in `block in <module:App>'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:399:in `run_block_and_record_step_progress'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:188:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'


I have used rbenv to install ruby. The rbenv versions produces
system
* 2.7.7 (set by /home/deploy/.rbenv/version)`

I have tried a few of the solutions that iIfound on Internet like changing the /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/passenger.conf file to change it to PassengerDefaultRuby /home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/ruby
I want my ruby version to be 2.7.7 as specified in my Gemfile, .ruby-version file in my application root directory.
